# Use old server IP address to New server

Tags: ip-address

Now we are going to use new server to host our website. We are going to use our old server IP address to new server. Can we replace our new server IP address by old server IP address?

If possible, please can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! :-)

It depends, is the server in the same network? If so you have to remove the IP-Address from the old the server (and may assign any temporary). Then you should be able to assign the old IP-Address to your new server.

BTW: This sounds like a question for http://serverfault.com.

Comment: :what you mean same network?

Comment: you might want to learn the basics first then. It *should* be a simple matter of assigning the ip address to the new system, which in turn should be a simple matter of setting the ip address as a static IP address on the new server... which... well, you need to know how to do. You might also want to take note of your OS (for setting the ip address)and networking setup (which is beyond my skills but might be useful). I see a serious lack of useful information in the question, and a lack of homework, so to speak